# Exposing DB within the application

Tags: database

How can I secure connection or db credentials when directly accessing the DB server over the internet from the client side application.

Answer (score 1):

Use SSL, or encrypt the user/password yourself before sending it.

Answer (score 0):

SSL or some other credential obfuscation (depends on database server) will work in the case where you have a remote client directly talking to the server, but that will require the remote side know the credentials.  If you want to prevent them from knowing the DB login information you'll have to write some form of adapter.

This question could use a lot more detail.